# Will there be more of "The man in the high castle"?

Tags: philip-k-dick, the-man-in-the-high-castle

Just finished watching Amazon's version of Philip K Dick's novel *The Man in the High Castle*.

Do the TV series and the Book currently end in the same way?

> Is there anything mentioned about the Japanese Trade minister returning to his reality in the Book?

Is there more to show in the TV series that is currently in the Book?

Comment: "Is that it?" is not a very good question for this site. I suggest you focus on a single, concrete, answerable question :) Asking multiple questions in a single post is also frowned upon.

Comment: http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/amazon-renews-man-high-castle-850153

Answer (score 11):

At the end of the novel *The Man in the High Castle*,

> Nobusuke Tagomi comes back to his own timeline, orders Frank Frink released, then has a heart attack.

However, the novel also lacks a complete resolution: Philip K Dick always planned to go back to it and write a sequel some day. From [this interview](http://www.philipkdickfans.com/literary-criticism/interviews/hour-25-a-talk-with-philip-k-dick/) (emphasis mine):

> But then when it came time to close down the novel the I Ching had no more to say. And so there’s no real ending on it. **I like to regard it as an open ending. It will segue into a sequel sometime**.
>
> [...]
>
> And that’s why I’ve never written a sequel to it. Because it’s too horrible. It’s too awful. **I started several times to write a sequel to it** and I would had to go back and read about Nazis again. And I’d just like to off every one of them, it’s what I’d like to do. And so I could never do a sequel to it. **Somebody would have to come in and help me do a sequel to it.** Someone who had the stomach for the stamina to think along those lines, to get into the head

For a longer discussion of the difference between the original novel and Amazon's version, see [here](http://io9.com/man-in-the-high-castle-is-wildly-different-from-the-boo-1679953073).